# Android error with importanceReasonComponent.getShortClassName(); ?

Tags: android

I have :
String list[];

```
ActivityManager m = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> process = m.getRunningAppProcesses();

list = new String[process.size()];
    for(int i=0;i<process.size();i++)
    {

        list[i]=process.get(i).importanceReasonComponent.getShortClassName();    

    }
```

if I try to run the app it force closes, please tell me what's the problem

Comment: Please add logs. What have you tried so far to figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at the logcat, we can't tell you what's wrong. That said, looking at the documentation, importance is only set for Services and ContentProviders.

You should check that `process.get(i).importanceReasonCode != RunningAppProcessInfo.REASON_UNKNOWN` before trying to get the component (which is probably `null` if the reason is `REASON_UNKNOWN`).